# column adding in query function gives additional field

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language, importrange

Hi am simply trying to add two columns but this formula gives me one additional field `sun()` in a cell. Look at the picture for this strange behaviour:

[image]

the formula i used is this :

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx","xxx!A1:Z")select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,(Col6)+(Col7),Col8")`

What is going on and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the [`label clause`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#label) as in:

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"select A+B label A+B 'Total' ")
```

[image: How to hide headers in a query SUM]

In your case the formula would be:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx","xxx!A1:Z")select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6+Col7,Col8 label Col6+Col7 '' ",0)
```

You do not need the extra `()` around the columns.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove it if you use:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx", "xxx!A1:Z"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6+Col7,Col8
  label Col6+Col7''")
```

or like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxx", "xxx!A1:Z"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6+Col7,Col8"),
 "offset 1", 0)
```